# Unexpected token when declaring vue component @Prop with typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, properties, phpstorm, vue-property-decorator

I'm trying to use typescript with vuejs, normally I use something like

```
  @Component({
    props: ['uploadUrl'],
  })

  export default class SelectionModal extends Vue {
    let x = this.uploadUrl // This variable `uploadUrl` is NOT resolved in my IDE
  }
```

but the uploadUrl is not resolved in my IDE (phpStorm)
[image]

But we can fix it with `vue-property-decorator`, by declaring @Prop like documented [here](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator#Prop). The code becomes:

```
<template>
// ... 
</template>

<script type="ts">
  import {Component, Vue, Prop} from 'vue-property-decorator';
  
  @Component
  export default class SelectionModal extends Vue {
    @Prop(String) readonly uploadUrl!: string

    let x = this.uploadUrl // This variable `uploadUrl` is RESOLVED in my IDE
  }
</script>
```

[image]

However, this basic declaration fires such issue

```
SyntaxError: /myProject/src/path/to/MyComponent.vue: Unexpected token (33:25)

  31 | 
  32 | export default class SelectionModal extends Vue {
> 33 |   @Prop(String) readonly uploadUrl!: string
     |                          ^
```

Anyone here has an idea :

1- how to use the 1st solution and make the `uploadUrl` resolved

2- OR how to get ride of the `Unexpected token` issue ?

Comment: Can you create a typescript playground that replicates the issue? I tried something similar [in this playground, but it works fine already.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true&ssl=5&ssc=24&pln=5&pc=14#code/FAEwpgxgNghgTmABBA9gOwM4BdEZQWzABFIAuRACgEpEBeAPkQAU4UAHMOLATxNThhYUcANzBg0GBgyIAYihSIA3omCJ1iAAJ5CfaogQwQ6KN0QAjeAEJy2OAEs0AczEBfYEA)

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `<script lang="ts">`, ie, with `lang` not `type`? I notice that the `readonly` declaration is the first part of the code you show which is not valid javascript so my guess is that vue is not transpiling that script into js due to the incorrect `lang` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example doesn't compile - you can't declare `let` directly in the class body, and accessing the props through `this.prop` causes " Property 'prop' does not exist on type..." error when building the app.

The second code snippet works fine for me when using the right `<script>` tag attributes - try changing `type` to `lang` to have your code treated as a Typescript source:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import {Component, Vue, Prop} from 'vue-property-decorator';
  
  @Component
  export default class SelectionModal extends Vue {
    @Prop(String) readonly uploadUrl!: string
    
    myMethod(){
      let x = this.uploadUrl 
    }
  }
</script>
```